# Extract SSL certificate details from website using Selenium - Chrome driver

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, selenium-chromedriver, ssl-certificate

Is it possible, using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) and [Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/), to access informations about the SSL certificate used on the current website?

For example, given the url https://google.com, I would like to extract the following:

[image]

Comment: Your code trials?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium does not provide API for extracting certificates. You can extract what you need using standard python libs:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172133/8343843
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30863209/8343843